# applying the divergence theorem in all coordinates

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

My Question is : 
is the divergence theorem same on cylindrical and cartesian coordinates?

Ex:

$$\iint \vec{gradA}\, \vec{dS} = \iiint \operatorname{div} \vec{gradA}\, dV $$

is this expression is true in all coordiantes?

thanks in advance,

Comment: What *means* "true in all coordinates"? The LHS is a surface integral, so the question doesn't makes sense. And in the RHS, you can calculate the triple integral using any suitable change of variable.

Comment: true in all coordinates means : is valid for (cartesian, cylindrical ans polar coordinats).

Comment: Again: the question *doesn't makes sense* for a *surface* integral. The volume integral can be calculated using *any* change of variable, including cylindrical, spherical...